# asp.net pop up window no response shows end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview

I am trying to create a modal popup window to display row details from grid view. But when I click the link button, there is no response. 
I tried the tutorial from [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atYE32-qtA0)

I am getting an error in browser console as: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. What does this error points to? I have added the text box controls for the pop up div too as suggested in comments. What is the cause of this error?

```
<%----------- POP UP CONTENT --------------------%>
<div id="popupdiv" title="EditStd" style="display:none;"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="ppID" Text="" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox> 
    <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px;">
        <span style="float: left; width: 40%;"><b>Reg/Sym:</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ppReg" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>/
            <asp:TextBox ID="ppSym" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px;">
        <span style="float: left; width: 40%;"><b>Address:</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ppAddress" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </span>
    </div>  
</div>
<%------------------------------------------------------%>
<asp:GridView ID="StdGrid" Visible="false" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="#" onclick="popup("<%# Eval("STUDENT_ID") %>")", 
                                        "<%# Eval("SYMBOL_NO") %>")", 
                                        "<%# Eval("REG") %>")",
                                        "<%# Eval("ADDRESS") %>")">Update</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>                                 

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(id, sym, reg, addrs) {
            alert("test");
            $("#ppID").text(id);
            $("#ppSym").text(sym);
            $("#ppReg").text(reg);
            $("#ppAddress").text(addrs);
            $("#popupdiv").dialog({
                title: "Edit Student",
                width: 350,
                height: 250,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is not complete one... The textbox controls are missing!

Comment: @Vikrant I have updated my code. Please check. Thank You!!!

Comment: Why is the **/** slash at the end of textbox with Id "ppReg"? and also.. Is `alert("test")` is getting called?

Comment: try with this,
 <a href="#" onclick="popup("<%# Eval("STUDENT_ID") + "," + 
                                        Eval("SYMBOL_NO") + ",'" + 
                                         Eval("REG") + "'" %>")",
                                        "<%# Eval("ADDRESS") %>")">Update</a>